# Page displaying response instead of content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm developing a webpage using express for the backend and reactjs for the frontend. All the different views work correctly with their routes in react. But when I create a webpack and run the app on express, there is one route that shows me the response I get instead of the webpage content.

This is how I declare my routes in react.

```
 <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path="/menu/:accessToken" component={MainPage} /> 
</Router>
```

And this is the get method for the main page in express

```
router.get('/menu/:accessToken', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("OK");
});
```

Comment: which port is your react app running on and which port is your express app running on?

Comment: React is running on 3000, and express is running in 3001

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending a string in response, you need to send html i.e. index.html file of react app for all urls, which will resolve route based on your routes.

```
router.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(indexHtmlFile); // set proper content-type etc. This is not exact code to copy paste
});
```

Comment: I thought about that, but my login page works and the get method is exactly the same, the only difference is the route.

Comment: IMO, you don't need server for react app, unless you need server side rendering, you can simply deploy your app on some static content delivery service like AWS S3 or Firebase Hosting etc.